# Axis label position in pgfplots using axis description cs

Tags: pgfplots, axis

In the following example the x axis label and the node have the same coordinates in the axis description cs. Why are they placed at different positions? How does the label positioning work exactly?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmin=0.75, xmax=2.25, ymin=1, ymax=1.3, x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.05,1)}}, xlabel={$k$}, clip=false]
  \node at (axis description cs:1.05,1) {$k$};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the MWE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you were right, but `x label style` **appends** the options to the already given ones. And as it seems the default style (when no `compat` level is given) uses a negative `yshift` (and also another `anchor`). So to give an "unappended" style use `every axis x label/.style` which results in the expected result.

(Alternatively you could also use at least `compat=1.3` which changes the default `x label style` and then really "just" append stuff using again that style, i.e. `x label style`. For that see the commented parts of the code.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0.75,
        xmax=2.25,
        ymin=1,
        ymax=1.3,
        every axis x label/.style={
            at={(axis description cs:1.05,1)},
        },
%        x label style={
%            at={(axis description cs:1.05,1)},
%            anchor=center,
%        },
        xlabel={$k$},
        clip=false,
    ]
        \node [text=red] at (axis description cs:1.05,1) {$k$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]